# how to display a logout button once the users lpgs in

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, master-pages

i have a logout [link button] in master page and i want to show it once the user logs in.
I did this way

```
protected void LoginAction_Click(object sender, EventArgse)
    {

    LinkButton btnSignout = (LinkButton)Master.FindControl("btnLogout");
        if (btnSignout != null)
        {
            btnSignout.visible=True;
        }

        Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `LoginStatus` in `LoggedInTemplate` control

```
 <LoggedInTemplate>
    <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" OnLoggedOut="LoginStatus1_LoggedOut"                                             
    LogoutText="Sign Out" CssClass="linkLoginControls" />
 </LoggedInTemplate>
```

`LoggedInTemplate` will be visible when the user logged in

Comment: Thanks , but i dont have to use this Loginstatus control.

Comment: Why you don't want to use this ? This is built control available for specially such purpose.

Comment: actually..that is not my requirement i have to do without using this built in security controls

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking for but it sounds like you are wondering how to reference content in the master page?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx

Comment: i want to display the logout button on the header once the user logs in

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a loginstatus control then you can check on page load if the user is authenticated, and if so have your logout button/hyperlink there set to visible.